# Как изменить направление поля input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textinputlayout

Как я могу поменять направление поля ввода текста? То есть, я хочу, чтобы оно было не строго горизонтально или вертикально, а под углом или, может быть, с небольшим изгибом. Можно ли это реализовать средствами чистого html/css, если нет, то как? (Есть небольшой опыт react.js)

Comment: transform: rotate(45deg)

Comment: А можно его как-то изогнуть? Понимаю, что вопрос странный, но всё же

Comment: Теоретически, можно хоть в восьмёрку скрутить. Проблема в дальнейшей юзабельности - например, выделение текста. А если к тому же на мобиле... УжОс! Представьте велосипед с треугольными колёсами - креативно и даже более устойчивый на парковке... но, кататься то как?

Comment: Вот мне как раз нужен способ как его скрутить в восьмерку, хотя бы даже теоретически. Про юзабельность речи нет - это именно для создания wow-эффекта. Скорее всего, до конечного юзера это даже и не дойдёт, так, побаловаться и убедиться, что так можно